# Ho to configure WordPress with GitLab

Tags: wordpress, continuous-integration, gitlab, cpanel, continuous-deployment

I'm pretty new to this, but I want to configure my GitLab repo to my Cpanel hosting account. So when I push changes from my local site (environment using local by flywheel) to GitLab it automatically goes to the staging site and if everything is good to the production site.

I have managed to connect my Cpanel account with GitLab by using Deploy HQ. However, I'm trying to understand the best way to set all of this up. Currently, I'm only tracking my themes folder in GitLab. My issue is that when I deploy, all that is getting uploaded is the themes folder(obviously). How do I set this up so it will upload the full WordPress site and database? Also, how do I set it up with staging and production, would I have two different branches connected to two different directories on cpanel?

I'm just looking for some noob friendly advice on how to set up this infrastructure for WordPress Git and Cpanel.

Comment: Try with this article, https://www.daviddarke.dev/blog/deploying-to-wp-engine-from-a-gitlab-pipeline-ci-cd/